# intersection of a hypersurface and a quasi affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, krull-dimension

Exercise I1.7 in Hartshorne states if $Z$ is an affine variety of dimension $r$ and $H$ a hypersurface then either $Z \subset H$ or every irreducible component $Z \cap H$ is dimension $r-1$. My question is does this hold more generally where we replace irreducible $Z$ with $Z \setminus V$ with some Zariski closed subset $V$?

In other words, suppose $Z$ is an affine variety and $V$ is some Zariski closed subset of $Z$, and $\dim Z \setminus V = r$. Then either $(Z \setminus V) \subset H$ or every irreducible component of $(Z \setminus V) \cap H$ is dimension $r-1$?

I was wondering if removing a closed subset could have some effect on this nice behavior

edit. I changed pure dimension of $r-1$ to every irreducible component is dimension $r-1$.

Comment: Do you mean: Given $Z$ affine subvariety of affine space A^n of dimension $r$, and a closed subset $V$ in $A^n$, is it true that either $Z\subset V$ or $Z\cap V$ is of pure dimension $r-1$?

Comment: @EvansGambit I meant to write setminus and not intersection. I corrected the typo and fixed question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take $Z=\mathbb{A}^1\subset \mathbb{A}^2$ as the $x$-axis. Let $H=y$-axis.
Then $Z\cap H=(0, 0)$ of dimension 0.

Let $V=(0, 0)$. $Z-V= \mathbb{A}^1-(0, 0)$.

Now $Z-V\nsubseteq H$, and $(Z-V)\cap H=\emptyset$ so of dimension $-1$ or $-\infty$ depending on your preference.

Comment: Good counterexample. You may want to note that if you require $V$ to be codimension at least two in $Z$, then everything works out and the result is still true.

Comment: @HankScorpio is there a reference where I can find the result?

Comment: Thank you for this example. Is there an example where $(Z-V) \cap H \neq \emptyset$? I was checking the book and it looks like being an empty set is allowed, every irreducible component has dim $r-1$ is what it says, which seems to allow empty sets? I initially thought this means pure dimension $r-1$ but I'm not so sure now....

Comment: @SJY You can prove it yourself, there's no need for a reference: since every irreducible component of $V\cap H$ is contained in $V$, $\dim V\cap H\leq\dim V$, and either $Z\subset H$ or $Z\cap H$ is of pure codimension one. In the first case, nothing happens; in the second case, since $\dim V<\dim Z-1$, $V\cap H$ cannot be all of an irreducible component of $Z\cap H$.